# How do I access APIs without using NetworkCredential in C#/UWP?

Tags: web-services, api, http, asp.net-web-api, networkcredentials

I got some of the APP's APIs.
When I use the browser to access these APIs, the browser popup window tell me to fill in the username/password, Then I tried to fill out my username/password and found that I passed the verification!
Then I tried to write the code

```
var myClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
myClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc", "!@#");

this._client = new HttpClient(myClientHandler);
this._client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.xxx.com");
var result = await this._client.GetStringAsync("some_api_foo.json");
```

Run well!

**(We know that if there are no NetworkCredential, there will be 401 unauthorized exception)**

But I found out that the official APP could access some of the APIs without the user logging in. How does it work? Does it use a public account? Or is there another way to access the APIs?

Answer (score 0):

It uses Windows [integrated authentication (Kerberos)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication) to authenticate your users without asking them for credentials

Comment: Thank you, I've found the fiddler authorization condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler >check Authorization Header is present: **Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**

**xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx** is **Username:Password**(**Base64**)
Decrypt it!